# Cordova new App from older files

Tags: cordova

I need to update an app created with Cordova but the guy who created the app only sent me the WWW folder, I'm new to Cordova and I was wondering.. is it correct or he has to send me other files (for example for configurations, ecc..) ?

Also is there a command line to build the project he sent me or do I need to create a new project in order to build it? Because reading the api I found anything regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello oSigno and welcome to cordova ;-)

The www folder is enough. You only need to rebuild that application but i would recommend you to generate a total new project. Go on like i describe:

1. First of all: Be sure you installed cordova the right way into your console/terminal. Type `cordova` into it and you should get some information about it.
2. Move to your desktop with the `cd` command and generate a new cordova project with `cordova create ProjectName com.companyName.com ProjectName` the first "ProjectName" is the folder name and the second "ProjectName" is the name, displayed for the app.
3. Open up the new Folder "ProjectName" and copy the files from the `www` folder (the one you got from the first developer) into your new www folder inside your "ProjectName" folder .
4. Next step: Add the platforms you want to develop for with the command `cordova platform add ios`. You can replace ios with `android` or another OS.
5. Add the Plugins you need next. You can find them inside the www folder. There should be a folder Plugins. Install them step by step with the command `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device` for example. Maybe you will not find all plugins in the cordova Plugin-Database. Just Google the names from them and install them via GitHub.
6. Build your Project via `cordova build`. After that is finished, you're able to compile the app with android studio, xcode or anything else.

If you need further help let me know and i'll inform you about the next steps!

Comment: god that was easy :P perfect guide thank you again! just having a problem when exporting for android but it's because i'm missing the sdks for 4.4.2

Answer (score 0):

You need the www folder + plugins folder (if the project has any).

```
 1)   Create a phonegap project;   "phonegap create projectName --id com.apps.projectName  --name projectName"  

 2) Then go to the project folder and commit, "phonegap build android". 

 3)  Afterwards, replace the created project's www folder with your www. 

 4) Say :  "phonegap build android"  .
```

Ps: The guy needs to tell you the list of plugins used in project ( if any) .

```
 5) You should add them one by one ; e.g ;  cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

Comment: And there could be other changes in configurations. Also, you will lose all the image resources which you might have used for splashscreen/icon. So it would be better to know all the changes; or tell them to send over the whole project's folder.